# forgot the technical term for capturing a value in returned function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

What is a function called that returns a function with earlier passed values populating it?

I know it's not a continuation, but I forget the functional-programming name for it.

Sorry this is a horrible question; my memory is just really bad today.

```
function negate(func) {
  return function(x) {
    return !func(x);
  };
}
```

Comment: A higher-order function? A closure?

Comment: Yes! It's a closure! That's the word I was looking for.

Comment: `negate` is a closure too, not just the inner function. the `function` keyword in javascript is just *syntax* for creating a closure.

Comment: @naomik However, `negate` doesn't depend upon its lexical environment. Although it's a closure in practice yet it's not a closure in theory. =)